# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'errcap' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I encountered the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'errcap' of undefined" in my chrome.

[image]

On the firefox, i encountered this one: 
[image]

I'm using jqgrid 4.8.2.

And here is my code:

```
$("#Grid").jqGrid({
    url: "/Templates/Dometic/Services/DometicGenral.svc/GetVehiclesByOemId",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    height: 'auto',
    colNames: [
    'Edit',
    'ID',
    'Vehicle brand',
    'Model Information',
    'Created by',
    'Date created',
    'Last modified by',
    'Date last modified',
    'Manage products'
    ],
    shrinkToFit: true,
    colModel: [
        {
            name: "EditAction",
            width: 60,
            fixed: true,
            search: false,
            sortable: false,
            resize: false,
            formatter: "actions",
            formatoptions: {
                keys: false,
                editbutton: true,
                delbutton: false,
                editformbutton: false,
                onSuccess: function (response) {
                    if (response.status == 200) {

                        $("#Grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid"); //Reloads the grid after edit

                        return [false];
                    } else {
                        return [true];
                    }
                },
                extraparam: {
                    oper: "edit",
                    Id: function () {
                        var sel_id = $("#Grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                        var value = $("#Grid").jqGrid("getCell", sel_id, "Id");
                        return value;
                    }
                },
                url: "#"
            }
        },
    //{ name: 'Id', index: 'Id', key: true, sortable: false, search: false, width: 80, title: false, formatter: editcoulmnformatefunction },
    //{ name: 'Id', index: 'Id', sortable: false, search: false, width: 60, title: false, formatter: deleteFormatter },
    { name: 'Number', index: 'Number', editable:false, width: 80, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'], clearSearch: false }, title: false },

    {
        name: 'Brand', index: 'Brand', sortable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'], clearSearch: false }, title: false,
        editable: true, edittype: 'custom', editoptions: {
            custom_element: editBrandFormatter,
            dataInit: function () { AutocompleteBrand(); }
        }
    },

    {
        name: 'Model', index: 'Model', editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'], clearSearch: false }, title: false,
        edittype: 'custom', editoptions: {
            custom_element: editModelFormatter,
            dataInit: function () { AutocompleteModel(); }
        }
    },

    { name: 'CreatedBy', index: 'CreatedBy', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'], clearSearch: false }, title: false },
    {
        name: 'DateCreated', index: 'Email', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'], clearSearch: false }, title: false,
        formatter: function (cellValue) { return cellValue!= null? ConvertJsonDateStringToString(cellValue, serverOffset):''; },
    },
    { name: 'ModifiedBy', index: 'Telephone', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'], clearSearch: false }, title: false },
    {
        name: 'DateModified', index: 'MobilePhone', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'], clearSearch: false }, title: false,

        formatter: function (cellValue) { return cellValue != null ? ConvertJsonDateStringToString(cellValue, serverOffset) : ''; },
    },
    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'], clearSearch: false }, title: false, formatter: manageProductFormatter }
    ],
    pager: '#GridPager',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100],
    viewrecords: true,
    jsonReader: {
        records: "records",
        total: "total",
        page: "page",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "Id"
    },
    sortname: 'Id',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    loadui: 'block',
    autowidth: true,
    altclass: 'odd',
    altRows: true,
    postData: {
        OemId: $("#hndOemId").val()
    },
    toppager: true
});
```

The error happens when i click on the save icon like the image bellow:
[image]

Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: Have you included the grid.locale-en.js file?

Comment: yes, i have included  grid.locale-en.js file

Comment: Look at my answer, which I modified. I included **two** lines of code with the same error instead of one line posted in my original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can add javascript to your page

```js
//fix for jqgrid 
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795713/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-errcap-of-undefined
$.jgrid.getRegional = function(inst, param, def_val) {
    try{
        if (inst instanceof jQuery){
            inst = inst.get(0);
        }
    }catch(e){}
    var ret;
    if(def_val !== undefined) {
        return def_val;
    }
    if(inst.p && inst.p.regional && $.jgrid.regional) {
            ret = $.jgrid.getAccessor( $.jgrid.regional[inst.p.regional] || {}, param);
    }
    if(ret === undefined ) {
        ret = $.jgrid.getAccessor( $.jgrid, param);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use jqGrid 4.8.2 myself because I develop alternative fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) after changing the licence agreement of jqGrid and making it [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Nevertheless I looked in the code and one can see the bug in [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.2/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L180-L181)

```js
var errors = $.jgrid.getRegional(this, 'errors'),
edit =$.jgrid.getRegional(this, 'edit'),
```

of code of `saveRow`. The correct code should be

```js
var errors = $.jgrid.getRegional($t, 'errors'),
edit = $.jgrid.getRegional($t, 'edit'),
```

where `$t` is equal to `this[0]` (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.2/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L150)). You can make the modifications on the code of `jquery.jqGrid.js` (see [the line 10179](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.js#L10179)) and use it instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to verify that the problem will be solved in the way.